# How to perform a Boolean test on a nested javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if all value in the object are true. I want to return true if all are true but return false if any one is false

```
{
    "2211284396232-5": {
        "2211284396232-5": true, 
        "644889430161": {
            "4812219518053": false, 
            "4812219518055": false,
            "4812219518063": false,
            "4812219518064": true,
            "4812219518069": false, 
            "644889430161": false
        }, 
    },
    
    "2211628865398-6": {
        "2211628865398-6": false, 
            "729563966440": {
                "5229922707373": false, 
                "729563966440": false
            }, 
    },
    
     "2212485574058-4": {
        "2212485574058-4": false, 
            "689399023594": {
                "5077186698704": true, 
                "5077186698712": false, 
                "689399023594": false
            }, 
    },
     
 }
```

I know of `every()` method but my problem is the object are nested so I don't know how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you can do is recursively flatten the object to an array of the values. Then you can call `every` on the result to test your result.

EDIT: updated the code with `reduce` and `Object.values` as suggested. I'm not a big fan of `reduce` as I find it less readable, and it makes people think that you save a variable reference where it's the contrary under the hood, the initial value is carried from one callback to another with 3 other parameters that have to be handled internally. I completely agree with `Object.values` and improper use of `map` (the original code should have used `forEach` instead probably, or even a simple `for`)

```js
let data = {
    "2211284396232-5": {
        "2211284396232-5": true, 
        "644889430161": {
            "4812219518053": false, 
            "4812219518055": false,
            "4812219518063": false,
            "4812219518064": true,
            "4812219518069": false, 
            "644889430161": false
        }, 
    },
    
    "2211628865398-6": {
        "2211628865398-6": false, 
        "729563966440": {
            "5229922707373": false, 
            "729563966440": false
        }, 
    },
    
     "2212485574058-4": {
        "2212485574058-4": false, 
        "689399023594": {
            "5077186698704": true, 
            "5077186698712": false, 
            "689399023594": false
        }, 
    },
     
 };
 
function recurseFlat(obj){
  return Object.values(obj).reduce(function (acc, cur) {
    if(typeof cur == 'object'){
      acc = acc.concat( recurseFlat(cur) );
    }else{
      acc.push(cur);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}

let flat = recurseFlat(data);

console.log('flatten: ', flat);

let result = flat.every((el) => el === true);

console.log('result: ', result);
```

(ORIGINAL CODE:)

```js
let data = {
    "2211284396232-5": {
        "2211284396232-5": true, 
        "644889430161": {
            "4812219518053": false, 
            "4812219518055": false,
            "4812219518063": false,
            "4812219518064": true,
            "4812219518069": false, 
            "644889430161": false
        }, 
    },
    
    "2211628865398-6": {
        "2211628865398-6": false, 
        "729563966440": {
            "5229922707373": false, 
            "729563966440": false
        }, 
    },
    
     "2212485574058-4": {
        "2212485574058-4": false, 
        "689399023594": {
            "5077186698704": true, 
            "5077186698712": false, 
            "689399023594": false
        }, 
    },
     
 };
 
function recurseFlat(obj){
  let acc = [];
  
  Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) {
    if(typeof obj[k] == 'object'){
      acc = acc.concat( recurseFlat(obj[k]) );
    }else{
      acc.push(obj[k]);
    }
  });
    
  return acc;
}

let flat = recurseFlat(data);

console.log('flatten: ', flat);

let result = flat.every((el) => el === true);

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but I would advocate against using .map without returning a value from the callback and ignoring calls return value. I would change it to reduce, instead of map, then you wouldn't even need to reference acc from higher scope within the callback.

Also you are using Object.keys only to use that key to access it's value. Realistically it would be much better to use Object.values

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski thanks for the suggestions, it wasn't a well thought answer, motivated by a problem-solving impulse. I'll edit when I have more time. Anyway I'm not a big fan of all functional approach when loops could be enough, adds overhead by creating callback functions, `reduce` makes people think it saves a variable when the second argument actually has to be carried from one call to another under the hood etc. But at least if I do it, I should do it right ;)

Comment: This is massively inefficient for no reason.

Comment: Yeah I'm a big failure, I noticed that too. Good bye all. Unfortunately I can't delete it

Answer (score 0):

Write recursive tester. Loop all values and check if it's boolean. If boolean - compare to true and return. If object - call itself once more.

```js
let data1 = {a: true, b: {c: true, d: {e: true}}};
let data2 = {a: true, b: {c: true, d: {e: false}}};
 
 function test(data, comparison) {
     if (typeof data == 'boolean') {
         return data === comparison;
     }
 
     for (let i in data) {
         if (!test(data[i], comparison)) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     
     return true;
 }
 
 console.log(test(data1, true), test(data2, true));
```

Comment: `data === true` is just `data` when `typeof data == 'boolean'`.

Comment: @Ry- Well yes, but I see it more readable.

Comment: I can't believe I came to a convoluted functionnal solution when I usually advocate for simple loops instead for readability and performance.. good answer

Comment: @Ry- I have updated my answer to show that `true` in `data == true` has different meaning than in other places.